# jQuery: Include an External Script After an Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to include an external jQuery script only after a certain jQuery event, for example, after fade in, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
      $('body').fadeIn(300, function() {

          // Include http://www.mydomain.com/js/myscript.js

});
}); 
</script>
```

Is something like that possible? Or, if not, perhaps there's a way to activate a script that has already been included, but kept "dormant"?

I would appreciate help from an expert!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has an AJAX method `$.getScript`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

```
$.getScript('http://www.mydomain.com/js/myscript.js',function(){
    /* new script has already run, can call additional code here if needed*/
})
```